MongooseError: Operation `clientusers.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
I'm working on a Next.js project where I use MongoDB for storage. I'm deploying the project using Azure Container Registry, and for containerization, I'm using Docker. Everything was working fine, but suddenly, I'm encountering the following error:
     2024-10-01T03:39:09.356177174Z: [ERROR]  MongooseError: Operation `clientusers.findOne()`      buffering timed out after 10000ms
     2024-10-01T03:39:09.356216274Z: [ERROR]      at Timeout.<anonymous>    (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185:23)
     2024-10-01T03:39:09.356223374Z: [ERROR]      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
     2024-10-01T03:39:09.356228474Z: [ERROR]      at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
     2024-10-01T03:39:09.356233274Z: [ERROR]    digest: '530784569'

I'm using this to connect mongodb,
   await mongoose.connect(connectionString as string, {
      user: process.env.MONGO_DB_USER as string,
      pass: process.env.MONGO_DB_PASSWORD as string,
      dbName: process.env.MONGO_DB_NAME as string,
      maxPoolSize: 1,
      socketTimeoutMS: 60000,
    });
    console.log('connected to mongoDB!');

But, this code works perfectly on my local host. If I run this via docker, it showing same issue.
How can I resolve this issue?
